# Android: Changing a View size

Tags: java, android

I have a View, kv which has a parent. I'm trying to move kv so its to the right half of the screen, currently its full width. This is my code

```
kv.getRootView().setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);
LayoutParams lp = kv.getLayoutParams();
lp.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
kv.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

idea is to pad the parent then make the kv fill the parent. However, it moves it left 50 pixels, but doesn't change width, so it goes of the screen. Any help?

If it matters, the `LayoutParams` I'm using is

```
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams
```

Comment: You are using `lp.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;` so it's width should be the full width. You can get the screen width and set the width to screenWidth / 2;

Comment: @zgc7009 MATCH_PARENT should ignore padding though

Comment: You are setting the width of the layout to the width of the parent, and then telling it you want padding of 50 which bumps it off the screen. You aren't saying you want it to be contained within the width of the parent, you are saying you want it to actually be that width. If you want to set width like that, get the actual width of the screen and set the width to the width of the screen minus your padding, in this case 50

Comment: @zgc7009 OK, just to test, i set the width to 50, and its still the same width. So clearly theres something wrong with code not logic

Comment: If you do lp.width = 50 it does the same thing? You have to be doing something somewhere to set your width somewhere else.

Comment: Thats the full code in the question

Comment: There is no way that is the full code in question. There have to be other places (like xml) where you work with those views. If that wasn't the case what you just did would have done something.

Comment: Its an Xposed mod I should have said. This is the keyboard view from com.google.android.inputmethod.latin